# Calculations between integers

Tags: objective-c, math, integer

I am trying to compute a ratio between two integers, likes and dislikes. It seems to be returning 0 instead of the number I should be getting in my calculator. What am I doing wrong?

```
int likes = 200;
int dislikes = 100;
float ratio = (likes / 2000) * ((likes / likes) + dislikes) * 100;
```

Comment: You're getting screwed by integer division.  Basic programming concept; google it.  You need to cast some stuff on the right side of your assignment to `(float)`.  E.g. `((float)likes / 2000.0f) * ...`

Comment: You're doing integer division, make 2000 2000.0

Comment: Also, not specific to Objective-C.  This is a feature of C.

Comment: So should I just make everything a float?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change:

```
int likes = 200;
int dislikes = 100;
float ratio = (likes / 2000) * ((likes / likes) + dislikes) * 100;
```

to:

```
float likes = 200;
float dislikes = 100;
float ratio = (likes / 2000) * ((likes / likes) + dislikes) * 100;
```

or cast it before doing the division like this

```
int likes = 200;
int dislikes = 100;
float ratio = ((float)likes / 2000) * (((float)likes / likes) + dislikes) * 100;
```

updated: with fixed typo as pointed out in comments

Comment: The casts should be `(float)likes`, not `float(likes)`.

Comment: oops you are correct, typing to fast and not thinking, I will fix

Answer (score 2):

Integers can't represent fractions, that's what makes them integers. Doing division with integers discards the remainder, thus if you try to divide a smaller integer by a larger integer, you get 0. You're on the right track with attempting to convert them to floats, but your current implementation performs the math on the integer values before doing the conversion. You need to convert `likes` and `dislikes` to `float` values before you do the calculation.